# Linq - OrderBy id when value in another list

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

i need your help on this one.

lets say:

```
public class myProduct
{
    public string Tags {get;set;} // Comma seperated values
}

List<myProduct> myProducts = WhatEver // Feeding the list products

List<long> capacity = WhatEverAlso // Feed the list long values from somewhere
```

now, what i want to do is order the myProducts list by capacity.

so , if a `myProduct.Tags` = "89,3,6"
and capacity = "1,2,3,4,5,6"

first will appear products with 1 in them, then 2 etc.

the problem is not ordering them, the problem actually is that some Tags do not contain capacity values.

**EDIT:**
for example, a products.tags could be "89,16,99"
so it does not contain any of the capacity values.
**EDIT2:**
I do not need to filter the products, just to order them.

**EDIT3:** 
i started to with `var foo = myProducts.OrderBy(p => p.Tags.Split(',').Intersect(capacity).OrderBy(c => capacity).Any());`
and i feel that im close, but i cant figure out the rest. :(

hope you understood my question, my expression in english is not that good :\
feel free to ask me for any additional information.

Comment: How do you know which ones do and do not have capacities? Can you just add a Capacity property to your MyProduct class? I get the feeling that IEnumerable<>.Join() is going to be part of the solution, but I can't really tell without more information.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need some foreach {} to do.

Comment: @itsme86 - added to the question an example

Comment: @DmitryBoyko - i have faith in Linq.

Comment: @Dementic then go ahead! :) If you are going to use LINQ I guess you need to use some intermediate class anyway.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko - i never said im not open to other solutions, all i said is that i think this is possible with pure linq.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko - if your interested, come and see that it is possible to do it, check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't entirely clear, but does this get you on the right track?

```
var ordered = 
    from p in myProducts
    let tags = p.Tags.Split(',').Select(long.Parse)
    let capIndices = 
        tags.Select(t => capacity.IndexOf(t))
        .Where(i => i >= 0)
    where capIndices.Any() // filter out products without capacity
    let capIndex = capIndices.Min()
    orderby capIndex
    select p;
```

This orders the products by the earliest location of any of its tags in the `capacity` list. If none of its tags are in the `capacity` list, a product is not included in the final results.